# Max Value multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I want rows in the output based on multiple conditions

Table X

```
id   name   orderdate  catalogprice
7b  34-10   NULL    3000
7b  34-10   NULL    3000
7b  34-10   NULL    2000
7b  35-12   PL-17   3000
8b  35-11   PL-18   4000
8b  34-13   PL-18   4000
8b  34-14   PL-18   4000
8b  34-15   PL-18   4000
9b  35-12   PL-19   5000
9b  35-11   PL-19   5000
9b  34-18   PL-19   5000
9b  34-19   PL-19   5000
9b  34-20   PL-19   5000
```

I want a List of the products

where Id starts with 7

where Name starts with 34

where Orderdate = null

whit the highest catalog price

Output should be this:

```
ID  Name    Orderdate   Catalog Price
7b  34-10   NULL    3000
7b  34-10   NULL    3000
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. [mcve]

Comment: `where id like '7%' and name like '34%' and orderdate is null` is a good start,

Comment: However, the specified result does not have the highest catalog price which is 5000. No row fulfills all conditions.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)